# socket.io emitting message to room does not work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Events binding for socket are moved to separate module:

```
exports.bind = function(socket) {
    socket.on('join', function(data) {
        socket.join(data.type);
    });
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
    global.io.sockets.in('rooma').emit('message', data);
    });
}
```

**server.js:**

```
var app = express();

//creating socket server
server = http.createServer(app);
io = global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {'log level': 3});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //binding events on socket
    events.bind(socket, io);
});
```

The problem is, that message is never sent to the clients in 'rooma'. But if i emit it global:

```
global.io.sockets.emit('message', data);
```

It works. Where can be problem? I've tested the client belongs to room for sure.

Answer (score 1):

this works when you get the initialisation of the event from the room to which you like to send your message:

```
exports.bind = function(socket) {
        socket.on('join', function(data) {
            socket.join(data.type);
        });
        socket.on('message', function(data) {
            socket.get('room', function (error, room) {
                io.sockets.in(room).emit('message', data);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: TypeError: socket.get is not a function